# device not mounted when run dockerui with docker

Tags: docker

after docker pull dockerui/dockerui
and follow the doc

> docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --privileged -v
>   /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock dockerui/dockerui

I get

> 698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9
>   FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: : exit status 2

but i can run tomcat container success , anyone can help me?

following is the docker daemon log

[root@docker-test ~]# docker -d

> INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
>
> INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
>
> ERRO[0000] WARNING: No --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev specified, using
>   loopback; this configuration is strongly discouraged for production
>   use
>
> INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()
>
> INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)
>
> INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.
>
> ....
>
> INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.
>
> INFO[0000] docker daemon: 1.6.0 8aae715/1.6.0; execdriver: native-0.2;
>   graphdriver: devicemapper
>
> INFO[0000] +job acceptconnections()
>
> INFO[0000] -job acceptconnections() = OK (0)
>
> INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization
>
> INFO[0012] POST /v1.18/containers/create
>
> INFO[0012] +job create()
>
> INFO[0012] +job log(create,
>   698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9,
>   docker.io/dockerui/dockerui:latest)
>
> INFO[0012] -job log(create,
>   698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9,
>   docker.io/dockerui/dockerui:latest) = OK (0)
>
> INFO[0012] -job create() = OK (0)
>
> INFO[0012] POST
>   /v1.18/containers/698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9/start
>
> INFO[0012] +job
>   start(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>
> INFO[0012] +job
>   allocate_interface(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>
> INFO[0012] -job
>   allocate_interface(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>   = OK (0)
>
> INFO[0012] +job
>   allocate_port(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>
> INFO[0012] -job
>   allocate_port(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>   = OK (0)
>
> INFO[0012] +job log(start,
>   698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9,
>   docker.io/dockerui/dockerui:latest)
>
> INFO[0012] -job log(start,
>   698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9,
>   docker.io/dockerui/dockerui:latest) = OK (0)
>
> WARN[0012] exit status 1
>
> INFO[0012] +job
>   release_interface(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>
> INFO[0012] -job
>   release_interface(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>   = OK (0)
>
> INFO[0013] +job
>   release_interface(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>
> INFO[0013] Unable to unmap port 0.0.0.0:9000: port is not mapped
>
> INFO[0013] -job
>   release_interface(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>   = OK (0)
>
> **ERRO[0013] Error unmounting device
>   698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9:
>   UnmountDevice: device not-mounted id
>   698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9**
>
> INFO[0013] +job log(die,
>   698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9,
>   docker.io/dockerui/dockerui:latest)
>
> INFO[0013] -job log(die,
>   698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9,
>   docker.io/dockerui/dockerui:latest) = OK (0)
>
> Cannot start container
>   698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9: [8]
>   **System error: [/usr/bin/tar -cf
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9274523689/_tmp.tar
>   -C /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9/rootfs/tmp
>   .] failed: /usr/bin/tar:
>   /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9/rootfs/tmp:
>   Cannot chdir: No such file or directory**
>
> /usr/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>
> : exit status 2
>
> INFO[0013] -job
>   start(698ba9df8c95d02631c95d88d7d798c592977299b121eb6d841dfa35c94165b9)
>   = ERR (1)
>
> ERRO[0013] Handler for POST /containers/{name:.*}/start returned
>   error: : exit status 2
>
> ERRO[0013] HTTP Error: statusCode=500 : exit status 2

Comment: docker version: Docker version 1.6.0, build 8aae715/1.6.0

Comment: I get `Unable to find image 'dockerui/dockerui:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from dockerui/dockerui
8260944ecb7d: Downloading 26.62 kB/1.284 MB
8260944ecb7d: Error downloading dependent layers 
70d943b8199f: Downloading 153.4 kB/413.9 kB
9ac79962b9b0: Download complete 
9ac79962b9b0: Error pulling image (latest) from dockerui/dockerui, Untar re-exec error: exit staError pulling image (latest) from dockerui/dockerui, Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: unexpected EOF
` so not much better than you when I `docker run`

Comment: i think may be your network is worse :)

Comment: DockerUI maintainer here, for what it's worth I'm able to pull and run the latest tag with no issues. Might be a problem with the Daemon itself.